# Element in completely different place in Firefox

Tags: css

I've got a video slider on this site http://fatdonut.ie/#projects . The problem I'm having is that the slider navigation controls , next and previous (#controls) are showing up in a completely different place in firefox . They should be just inside the slider , which they are in all other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `position:relative` to this id `#cc-slider` where the `absolute positioning` must be `relative` to another element